# SKPaymentTransaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt is nil

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app which has a Auto-renewable in-app purchase subscriptions option. Also the app has a 'Restore' option, the purpose of it is to restore the previous transactions.

But I am facing an issue in restoring, I am getting the 'transactionReceipt' as nil for the originalTransaction for every restored transaction. i.e "SKPaymentTransaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt" is received as nil. There by my validation of transaction receipt against AppStore is not getting happened.

Is anybody facing the same issue?

Any inputs would help me greatly.

Please note that I am testing the In-App purchase in Sandbox environment.

Thanks in advance,
Vasu N

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, so what I did was test the [transaction transactionReceipt] and Apple verifies it. Not sure if this is the correct way or not, but at least I am getting it verified by Apple. That is really all I care about as long as I can verify it isn't a fraudulent transaction I am happy.

The documentation says you should be able to get orig receipt but I have not been able to do so, I always find it == nil.

Comment: Even more strange, is that although NSLog states that SKPaymentTransaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt is null, during my SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored routine, for some bizarre reason, my app manages to add the correct receipt back into  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]. I actually think originalTransaction is not null, but NSLog displays it as null?

Comment: Forget that comment. I had another code snippet which I had forgotten about, which actually uses transaction.transactionReceipt, as a back-up, to populate the relevant [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] receipt variables. So, yes, we should use transaction.transactionReceipt NOT originalTransaction.transactionReceipt for our restore purchases routine.